# Getting Wordpress navigation inside another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to only get the worddpress navigation (header, navigation menu, footer) so I can 
add custom pages to the site which can easily integrate in the general template of the side while showing other things in the center instead of blog postings?

Edit: To clarify, I'd either like to know if there's an easy way to include the functions like `header()`, `footer()` (or whatever they're called) of Wordpress in another page, so where those functions are called, it echoes the general layout of Wordpress.

Or, I'd like to know which html files I can include to display the wordpress template's header, footer, and navagiation menu on a page.

What I'm trying to do is build my own pages on a website, outside of wordpress, which will use my own framework and php code, but call the wordpress's template to make the look & feel of the pages integrate with the rest of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines of code, then you can use whatever WP function you want:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Example from my own site:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
?>
```

Comment: Which other functions do you use? Can you also show how to include the wordpress navigation menu (if it isnt included in `get_header()`), and the footer at the bottom of the page?

Comment: sure - can you explain which "navigation menu" you're looking for? (this is a bit vague, i'm afraid)  If you're trying to make it display your entire theme, it depends a bit on how the theme makes use of the WP functions.  Generally, it's: "get_header(), get_sidebar(), <YOUR CONTENT>, get_footer()".  But take a look at your theme's "index.php" for how it's structured.

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_pages

What I would do is:

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
  <li>my page links...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also creating a "template" is as easy as naming the Template name in the top of your file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: PageOfPosts
*/

get_header(); ?>
```